# Executable which I am trying to run from a daemon script intermittently becomes inaccessible

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-not-found

I have a script written which tries to restart an executable if it is detected as stopped. However on occassion the script is unable to find the executable file, and it becomes accessible as soon as I log back into the machine using putty. Below are the logs for the phenomenon I am trying to describe.

```
Aug  4 23:41:24 USERNAME systemd[1]: my-scheduler.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug  4 23:41:24 USERNAME scheduler_startup[13535]: /usr/local/bin/scheduler_startup.sh: line 3: cd: /home/myUser/myFolder/Scheduler/dist/: No such file or directory
Aug  4 23:41:24 USERNAME scheduler_startup[13535]: /usr/local/bin/scheduler_startup.sh: line 4: ./Schedulercode: No such file or directory
Aug  4 23:41:24 USERNAME systemd[1]: my-scheduler.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Aug  4 23:41:24 USERNAME systemd[1]: my-scheduler.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug  4 23:41:24 USERNAME systemd[1]: my-scheduler.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug  4 23:41:29 USERNAME systemd[1]: my-scheduler.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug  4 23:41:29 USERNAME scheduler_startup[14213]: /usr/local/bin/scheduler_startup.sh: line 3: cd: /home/myUser/myFolder/Scheduler/dist/: No such file or directory
Aug  4 23:41:29 USERNAME scheduler_startup[14213]: /usr/local/bin/scheduler_startup.sh: line 4: ./Schedulercode: No such file or directory
Aug  4 23:41:29 USERNAME systemd[1]: my-scheduler.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Aug  4 23:41:29 USERNAME systemd[1]: my-scheduler.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug  4 23:41:29 USERNAME systemd[1]: my-scheduler.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug  4 23:41:35 USERNAME systemd[1]: my-scheduler.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug  4 23:41:35 USERNAME scheduler_startup[14889]: /usr/local/bin/scheduler_startup.sh: line 3: cd: /home/myUser/myFolder/Scheduler/dist/: No such file or directory
Aug  4 23:41:35 USERNAME scheduler_startup[14889]: /usr/local/bin/scheduler_startup.sh: line 4: ./Schedulercode: No such file or directory
Aug  4 23:41:35 USERNAME systemd[1]: my-scheduler.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Aug  4 23:41:35 USERNAME systemd[1]: my-scheduler.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug  4 23:41:35 USERNAME systemd[1]: my-scheduler.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug  4 23:41:40 USERNAME systemd[1]: my-scheduler.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug  4 23:41:41 USERNAME scheduler_startup[15313]: Scheduler Start - Version = 1.15 @Time: 2021-08-04 23:41:41.805467
```

As you can see on the last 2 lines, the restart attempt was successful and the application started running as expected. I am trying to find out what causes this temporary blindness to the executable in the system? and why is the file found again as soon as I log back in?

I am using is Ubuntu 20.xx

Comment: If you are using systemd, you don't need a script to determine if a program is running and restart it otherwise. You just use a systemd service file for this. And add a line defining what to do if the process stops ("Restart=always" or "Restart=on-failure").

Comment: Yes, my apologies, it is a systemd service file with 'Restart=always'. And you can see in the log that it is trying to restart, but cannot find the executable, and when I manually login to the server using putty, it is able to find the same file and runs properly.